# Adding information from a polygon layer to my attribute table from point layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, spatial-join

I have a point shapefile layer of animal observations and a polygon layer with 1 km x 1 km polygons of road density values. I'd like to add a column to the attribute table from the road density polygon data to my point layer. I'd like to grab the road density values that the observation points are located in and add them to my observation points attribute table. Do you have an idea of which tool I should be using for this?

Answer (score 1):

The tool you want is [**Spatial Join**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm).

When you run the tool, your Join Features will be the polygon layer and the Target Features will be the point layer.  This tool will create another feature class that has attributes of both.  You can then use an attribute join to link this new feature class back to the original point layer and update the appropriate attribute.